# Looking to ignore certain characters if entered in a Common Lisp program

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

***Updated formatting of the code.**

Good morning!

I'm teaching myself Common Lisp and I'm running into an issue where the program actually works, **except** if a certain character (",")is entered in as user input. The code (pretty short) is:

```
 (defun welcome ()
  (format t "Agent logged in. Status: Active, License to Kill: Active.~%~%"))


(defun getchoice3 ()
  (let ((choice  1))
  (format t  "~%Enter your password:  ")
   (let ((response (read)))
      (cond ((equal response '007)        
        (format t "~%~%Welcome James Bond, 007 ~%")(welcome))
        (t (format t "~%~%Incorrect Response!~%~%") (getchoice3))))))
           
(getchoice3)
```

If I update that code to try to catch the error, like:

```
(defun welcome ()
  (format t "Agent logged in. Status: Active, License to Kill: Active.~%~%"))


(defun getchoice3 ()
  (let ((choice  1))
  (format t  "~%Enter your password:  ")
   (let ((response (read)))
      (cond ((equal response '007)
          (if (#'symbolp (response))
          (getchoice3))
      (format t "~%~%Welcome James Bond, 007 ~%")(welcome))
      (t (format t "~%~%Incorrect Response!~%~%") (getchoice3))))))
           
(getchoice3)
```

It still works, and will go back to (getchoice3) on any symbol except ",".
If I code it to look for the symbol explicitly:

```
(defun welcome ()
  (format t "Agent logged in. Status: Active, License to Kill: Active.~%~%"))


(defun getchoice3 ()
  (let ((choice  1))
    (format t  "~%Enter your password:  ")
    (let ((response (read)))
      (cond ((equal response '007)
         (if (/, (response))
         (getchoice3))
      (format t "~%~%Welcome James Bond, 007 ~%")(welcome))
      (t (format t "~%~%Incorrect Response!~%~%") (getchoice3))))))
           
(getchoice3)
```

It still fails on the "," symbol and tells me that symbol doesn't have a backquote.

Ultimately I want the program to accept any letter or number, but no symbols and if it's entered, just ignore it and ask for input.

Any thoughts?   Thank you!

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Your code is unreadable as it is now.

Comment: **DON'T USE `READ` HERE**.  Unless you know *exactly* what you are doing, using `read` is opening yourself to horrible code-injection attacks.  `read` is *almost never* the right thing to handle user input.

Comment: @sds I undertstand what you're saying. I've corrected the indentation. Hopefully that's better (as I said I'm still learning!). Also, thank you for pointing out that read-line is what I should be using - *also* **thank you** for **only nudging me** in the right direction. I prefer this rather than an answer in code!

Comment: @tfb Thanks! I was looking to limit the user input to letters or numbers as I'd noticed the "," symbol was causing the program to crash. Thanks for the heads up about read, however. I'll remember it!

Comment: No, please use Emacs to indent automatically or read https://lisp-lang.org/style-guide/

Answer (score 4):

You are reading **text**, not **Lisp code/data**, so you should be using
[`read-line`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm) instead of
[`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Your code to read user input:

```
(format ...)
...
(read)                ; input would be a Lisp data, using Lisp syntax
```

That should be something like this:

```
(format ...)
...
(finish-output ...)  ; make sure output happens before waiting for input
(read-line ...)      ; input would be text, returned as a string
```

Answer (score 0):

(This answer had a glaring error that was picked up by @ad absurdum - Thank you very much!)

(updated - rookie mistake has now been corrected - thank you again @ad-absurdum!)

I appreciate your assistance, especially @ad absurdum and @sds.

If anyone else needs to see the correct code, it's one change only, change (read) to (read-line), as they suggested:

```
(defun welcome ()
  (format t "~% Status: Logged In   Agent ID: 007   License to Kill:Active     Messages from M: 0~%~%"))


(defun getchoice3 ()
  (let ((choice 1))
    (format t  "~%Enter your password:  ")
    (let ((response (read-line)))
      (cond ((string-equal response "007")
         (format t "~%~%Welcome James Bond, 007 ~%")(welcome))
        (t (format t "~%Incorrect Reponse.~%") (getchoice3))))))

(getchoice3)
```

Thank you again for your assistance!

Comment: Why do you want to use `read` to read a user-input password? This is a terrible idea, just asking for trouble. `read-line` is the right solution, unless you have some other goals not stated.

Comment: @adabsurdum My goal was to get the program to accept user input but not crash if characters like "," were entered.  I'm aware that if the program can be made to crash, it can be used to spawn shells and cause other mischief. The code I posted keeps running even if ","  or " "  or other kinds of code is entered.  I will remove my prior message and try again with read-line instead. Thank you.

Comment: `read-line` won't "crash" your program if you enter a comma; it is used to fetch a line of input, and returns a string. `response` in your posted code is a string, so your comparison should be something like `(string-equal response "007")`.